# Calculate zero waste when cutting the tape into a trapezoids

Tags: c#, algorithm, optimization

The task is to come up with an algorithm to cut the tape into a given number of trapezoids with zero waste.
Waste is the area of the cut-off surface for a given placement of trapezoids.

Trapezoids have same height, point A is always (0,0)

n - count of trapezoids

bx - x coordinate of point b

cx - x coordinate of point c

dx - x coordinate of point d

Trapezoids are specified from a file in the format:

```
n
b1x c1x d1x
...
bnx cnx dnx

Example:
10
-100 0 500
-900 -100 500
-1400 -400 500
-500 -400 500
-900 -400 500
-1300 500 500
0 400 500
-800 -800 500
-900 -900 500
-600 -300 500
```

Program.cs

```
using Minimization;

const int h = 10;

decimal StartArea(int bx)
{
    return Math.Abs(bx) * h / 2;
}

decimal EndArea(int cx, int dx)
{
    return Math.Abs(cx - dx) * h / 2;
}

decimal Area(int cx, int dx, int bx)
{
    return (cx < dx && bx < 0) || (cx > dx && bx > 0) ?
        (Math.Abs(cx - dx) - Math.Abs(bx)) * h / 2 :
        (Math.Abs(cx - dx) + Math.Abs(bx)) * h / 2;
}

var path = @"c:\tests\9.txt";

var trapezoids = FileUtilities.GetTrapezoids(path);

List<(int bx, int cx, int dx, int index)> startCandidates = new();

for (var i = 0; i < trapezoids.Length; i++)
{
    if (StartArea(trapezoids[i].bx) == 0)
        startCandidates.Add((trapezoids[i].bx, trapezoids[i].cx, trapezoids[i].dx, i));
}


var candidates = new Dictionary<int, HashSet<int>>();

for (var i = 0; i < trapezoids.Length; i++)
{
    candidates[i] = new HashSet<int>();
    for (var j = 0; j < trapezoids.Length; j++)
    {
        if (i == j) continue;
        if (Area(trapezoids[i].cx, trapezoids[i].dx, trapezoids[j].bx) == 0)
            candidates[i].Add(j);
    }
}

var res = new List<int>();

foreach (var (bx, cx, dx, index) in startCandidates)
{
    var currentIndex = index;
    var currentList = new List<int> { currentIndex };

    res = PossibleList(currentIndex, currentList, trapezoids);

    if (res != null)
    {
        break;
    }
}

List<int>? PossibleList(int currentIndex, List<int> currentList, Span<(int bx, int cx, int dx)> trapezoids)
{
    var nextCandidates = Except(candidates[currentIndex], currentList);

    if (nextCandidates.Count == 0)
        if (currentList.Count == candidates.Count && EndArea(trapezoids[currentIndex].cx, trapezoids[currentIndex].dx) == 0)
            return currentList;
        else
            return null;

    foreach (var candidate in nextCandidates)
    {
        var nextList = currentList.ToList();
        nextList.Add(candidate);

        var possible = PossibleList(candidate, nextList, trapezoids);

        if (possible != null)
            return possible;
    }

    return null;
}

HashSet<int> Except(HashSet<int> candidates, List<int> currentList)
{
    var res = new HashSet<int>();

    foreach (var candidate in candidates)
    {
        if (!currentList.Contains(candidate))
            res.Add(candidate);
    }

    return res;
}
```

I use a recursive algorithm to find the next point, but it works slowly with a large number of trapezoids in the file

How can i do it more efficiently?

Comment: What is your strategy in words?

Comment: I find the first trapezoid as a trapezoid with minimal StartWaste. Each next one by the minimum Waste to the current one. A problem in the calculations arises when several trapezoids have a minimum waste

Comment: I think there are counter examples even if always only one trapezoid has minimal waste to the current one. In other words: minimal waste to previous is not always the best choice.

Comment: Yes, and it is an issue. I think about recursive algorythms, but don't know how it implement. If calculate all possible placement options, then the number is too large. For 1000 trapezoids it will be 1000 factorial

Answer (score 1):

I think I can "prove" that the problem is NP-hard by converting it to a "directed" travelling salesman problem:

I don't really understand whether a and b are always at the top or a and c. Anyway it doesn't really matter, you can normalize so that a, b, c and d are the x-coordinates of the points top-left, top-right, bottom-left and bottom-right. Then we can define the overlap `overlap(x, y)` as follows:

```
public int overlap(int x, int y) {
    int dX = x.a - x.b;
    int dY = y.c - y.d;
    if (dX <= 0) {
        if (dY >= 0)
            return 0;
        return Math.max(dX, dY);
    } else {
        if (dY <= 0)
            return 0;
        return -Math.min(dX, dY);
    }
}
```

Note that the overlap is 0 or negative and generally overlap(a, b) != overlap(b, a). So we can create a directed graph with the trapezoids as vertices and the overlap as edges. Let's introduce a new node that has distance 0 to (and from) all other nodes. Now the problem corresponds to a "directed" travelling salesman problem: finding the shortest route through all the vertices visiting each vertex once and ending at the same vertex we started at. The solutions are all the shortest routes found. To get the order of the trapezoids we just have to start and end (and ignore) the introduced node following the shortest routes. The (absolute) length of the shortest route will be the amount of tape saved compared to cutting the bounding box for each trapezoid.

Comment: Thank you! I will try to build a graph and find the Euler path